# Reading file using fscanf() in C

Tags: c, file, readfile, scanf

I need to read and print data from a file.
I wrote the program like below,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main(void)
{
char item[9], status;

FILE *fp;

if( (fp = fopen("D:\\Sample\\database.txt", "r+")) == NULL)
{
    printf("No such file\n");
    exit(1);
}  

 if (fp == NULL)
{
    printf("Error Reading File\n");
}

while(fscanf(fp,"%s %c",item,&status) == 1)  
{  
       printf("\n%s \t %c", item,status);  
}  
if(feof(fp))  
{            
         puts("EOF");     
}  
else  
{  
 puts("CAN NOT READ");  
}  
getch();  
return 0;  
}
```

the database.txt file contains
Test1 A
Test2 B
Test3 C

When I run the code, it prints

> CAN NOT READ.

Please help me to find out the problem.

Comment: `fopen` can fail for many reasons.  Printing `"No such file"` is not useful when there is a permissions error.  `man perror`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

First of all, you're testing `fp` twice. so `printf("Error Reading File\n");` never gets executed.

Then, the output of `fscanf` should be equal to `2` since you're reading two values.

Answer (score 14):

`scanf()` and friends return the number of input items successfully matched. For your code, that would be two or less (in case of less matches than specified). In short, be a little more careful with the manual pages:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main (void) {
    FILE *fp = fopen ("D:\\Sample\\database.txt", "r+");

    if (!fp) {
        puts ("No such file\n");
        return -1;
    }

    char item[9] = {}, status = 0;
    while (true) {
        int ret = fscanf(fp, "%s %c", item, &status);
        if (ret == 2)
            printf ("\n%s \t %c", item, status);
        else if (errno != 0) {
            perror ("scanf:");
            break;
        } else if (ret == EOF) {
            break;
        } else {
            puts ("No or partial match.\n");
        }
    }
    puts ("\n");
    if (feof (fp)) {
        puts ("EOF");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) 
//while(42)
What it means?

Comment: It's equivalent to `while(1)` or in pseudocode `while(true)`.

Answer (score 3):

In your code:

```
while(fscanf(fp,"%s %c",item,&status) == 1)
```

why 1 and not 2? The scanf functions return the number of objects read.

Answer (score 1):

`fscanf` will treat 2 arguments, and thus return 2. Your while statement will be false, hence never displaying what has been read, plus as it has read only 1 line, if is not at EOF, resulting in what you see.