# How to read data in a file using fscanf

Tags: c

I have a table format in a file. I want to print it using fscanf. The table looks like this with 6 columns and 4 rows.

```
Name       Date          Opening    Amount     Type             Closing
Thiluxan   21.05.2015    8500       4500       Withdrawal       4000
Black      05.02.2014    7896       6548       Withdrawal       1348
Whitee     02.05.2015    8524       256394     Deposit          264918
```

```c
FILE *file1;
file1 = fopen("Bank.txt","r");
while(fscanf(file1, "%s %s  %s  %s  %s  %s", text) != EOF ) {
    printf("%s\n", text);
}
fclose(file1);
```

The output doesn't show anything and it returns a blank screen

Comment: You have 6 formatting fields in your format string, but you're only writing to 1 variable `text`. That causes undefined behavior.

Comment: You want to *print* it with `fscanf`? Do you know what `fscanf` does?

Comment: You are not checking the result of fopen.

Comment: @Barmar where is this specified?

Comment: related: [Reading file using fscanf() in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3351809/2513200)

Comment: The documentation of the `scanf` family of functions. Each formatting operator needs a corresponding variable to write to.

Comment: You can use `%*s` to specify that a field should be parsed but not written to a variable.

Comment: Ya thats a silly mistake i made. I failed to add 6 variables to save 6 data in a row. Thank you all for your solutions

Comment: @Barmar sorry misunderstanding on my part, I was thinking about something different.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in answer and comments above, you need to provide six variables into the fscanf arguments. Also it would be better if you have a model for your data. I would suggest to use a `struct` and input all data into an array of `structs`, that way you would be able to manage it better rather than managing random variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Bank {
    char name[100];
    char date[100];
    char opening[100];
    char amount[100];
    char type[100];
    char closing[100];
} Bank;

int main() {
    FILE *file1;
    file1 = fopen("Bank.txt","r");

    Bank bankList[100];
    int nCustomers = 0;
    while(fscanf(file1, "%s%s%s%s%s%s", bankList[nCustomers].name, bankList[nCustomers].date, bankList[nCustomers].opening, bankList[nCustomers].amount, bankList[nCustomers].type, bankList[nCustomers].closing) != EOF ){
            printf("%s %s %s\n", bankList[nCustomers].name, bankList[nCustomers].date, bankList[nCustomers].opening);
            nCustomers++;
    }
    fclose(file1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is the number of variables you passed into `fscanf`. 
If you want to read 6 strings you need to provide 6 string variables to save in

**Like So**

```
FILE * file1;
file1 = fopen("Bank.txt", "r");
while (fscanf(file1, "%s %s  %s  %s  %s  %s", t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6) != EOF) {
    printf("%s %s %s %s %s %s\n", t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6);
}
fclose(file1);
```

You have to instantiate all `t`s of course

Comment: In addition to that, it would be a good idea to check the return value of `fopen` as well as ensuring that the return value of `fscanf` is the expected number of arguments, instead of just checking it is not `EOF`.